# Pandas throwing QXcbConnection on subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running python version 3.6.3 anaconda with matplotlib.

If anyone knows what QXcbConnection is or how to fix it please let me know.

I've been able to narrow down to this simplest case

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(4)
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:33.0
Aborted
```

Not sure what has changed between today and yesterday. I did upgrade windows to a newer version.

I'm running on a remote linux server if that matters at all. I can include any systems settings but I dont know what to include at the moment.

Comment: `matplotlib` is not meant to run in any terminal, it's ideal to be ran in python script that output image as a file, or in an UI like jupyter notebook. I guess this connection error is due to no connection between terminal and the frontend display.

Comment: Ah I  see. That's unfortunate. I did find a work around however. Is it best to edit the solution into the OP, or post the work around as an answer?

Comment: It’s ok to answer it by yourself.